# Consolidate values from multiple tables without duplicate it

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tried to do the below example using joins and union but was not successful. I appreciate any assistance.

I have a **Student** table and 3 other tables of courses **Planed** to be done, current **Enrolled** and, **Concluded** course. For each of those courses tables, I have the FK_Student and the Course name. I do like to "join" all results in a single line for each course name with each course table as a column name. (The same course can be in multiple tables)
See example below:

```
Table: Student
Id_Student | Student
1           Bob
2 ...

Table: Planed
Id_Planed | Course | Fk_Student
1          History   1
2          English   1
3          Biology   1
4          Geometry  1
5          PE        1
6          Algebra   1
....

Table: Enrolled
Id_Enrolled | Enrollment | Fk_Student
1            History        1
2            Biology        1
3            PE             1
...

Table: Concluded
Id_Concluded | Conclusion | Fk_Student
1             History      1
2             English      1
3             Physics      1
...

Expected Result:
Student | Planed | Enrolled | Concluded
Bob      History   History   History
Bob      English   NULL      English      
Bob      Biology   Biology   NULL       
Bob      Geometry  NULL      NULL
Bob      PE        PE        NULL
Bob      Algebra   NULL      NULL
Bob      NULL      NULL      Physics
```

Comment: And what did you try? How does your query (join/union) looks like?

Comment: all tries gave me repeated left columns for each right column result

Answer (score 1):

**FULL OUTER JOIN** is used here because every subject name are not existed in all table. First subquery retrieve student wise Course, Enrollment and Conclusion record. Then **INNER JOIN** with student table as per expected output. If all student info needed then **LEFT JOIN** will be better. In Planed/Enrolled/Concluded table same Course/Enrollment/Conclusion can not assigned multiple time for particular student. As student_id and course needed for calculation so use two tables student_id and course inside **COALESCE()** so that always return **NOT NULL** value.

```
-- SQL SERVER (v2014)
SELECT s.Student, r.Course, r.Enrollment, r.Conclusion
FROM Student s
INNER JOIN (SELECT COALESCE(t.student_id, c.Fk_Student) student_id
                 , t.Course, t.Enrollment, c.Conclusion
            FROM (SELECT COALESCE(p.Fk_Student, e.Fk_Student) student_id
                       , COALESCE(p.Course, e.Enrollment) Course_t
                       , p.Course
                       , e.Enrollment
                  FROM Planed p
                  FULL OUTER JOIN Enrolled e
                               ON p.Fk_Student = e.Fk_Student
                              AND p.Course = e.Enrollment) t
                  FULL OUTER JOIN Concluded c
                               ON c.Fk_Student = t.student_id
                              AND c.Conclusion = t.Course_t) r
        ON s.Id_Student = r.student_id;
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=09d03c0b64d31c8ae5a3b91145b7b7e5

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your data model is somewhat flawed in its design, I would have expected a table of `Courses` with each course linked by a `Course_Id` to each student for each type.

I'm not clear on your desired output but it seems like you want a complete list of courses for each student and which of each are applicable in each case.

You can use a CTE to build a table of truth for all courses which is then cross-joined to Students so each student is presented with the full list of courses and then outer-joined to the 3 tables to indicate which courses are applicable to the student on each case.

```
with courses as (
    select course from planed union
    select enrollment from enrolled union
    select conclusion from concluded
)
select s.Student, p.Course Planed, e.Enrollment Enrolled, cc.Conclusion Concluded
from courses c
cross join student s 
left join planed p on p.course=c.course and p.fk_student=s.id_student
left join enrolled e on e.enrollment=c.course and e.fk_student=s.id_student
left join concluded cc on cc.Conclusion=c.course and cc.fk_student=s.id_student
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (no nested query or CTEs):

```
SELECT
  s.Student,
  p.Course,
  e.Enrollment,
  c.Conclusion
FROM Planed AS p
FULL JOIN Enrolled AS e
  ON e.Fk_Student = p.Fk_Student AND
     e.Enrollment = p.Course
FULL JOIN Concluded AS c
  ON (c.Fk_Student = p.Fk_Student AND
      c.Conclusion = p.Course) OR
     (c.Fk_Student = e.Fk_Student AND
      c.Conclusion = e.Enrollment)
RIGHT JOIN Student AS s
  ON s.Id_Student IN (
       p.Fk_Student,
       e.Fk_Student,
       c.Fk_Student
     );
```

Result:

```
+---------+----------+------------+------------+
| Student |  Course  | Enrollment | Conclusion |
+---------+----------+------------+------------+
| Bob     | History  | History    | History    |
| Bob     | English  |            | English    |
| Bob     | Biology  | Biology    |            |
| Bob     | Geometry |            |            |
| Bob     | PE       | PE         |            |
| Bob     | Algebra  |            |            |
| Bob     |          |            | Physics    |
| Sam     |          |            |            |
+---------+----------+------------+------------+
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=5a6b4e909a93e563674791a695d7bad9)